# aurelia router - pass one time param (param does not get recorded in browser history)

Tags: javascript, aurelia

**Is it possible to pass a parameter to a route that does not get recorded in the browser's history?**

I have requirements

- where a page has to save its previous info (when the user navigates away), which I am accomplishing by storing the data in a separate view-model.
- where, if the user hits the browser's history buttons, the page should reload itself using the saved data.

However, if they click a specific button somewhere else in the site, the user want to be navigated to this page but have it refresh it´s state. 
The problem I am running into is that suppose they click that button and it goes to

`/ThePageInQuestion?refresh=true`

and they navigate away and click the back button, the browser will go back to its history which will be the url above and the page will refresh itself. Of course this is not how it is supposed to work since when they click the back button, it should take them back with the saved settings in place. I need a way to go to the route and pass {refresh: true} as a parameter but not have it saved in the browser's history.

**Is this possible with the aurelia router?**

**If not, perhaps I can just manipulate the browser's history manually to remove this from the url?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 templates, one with cached content and one with no-cache.
Using the cache-control in META Tag.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Or try using vanilla js

```
history.go(number|url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
attached() {
        window.history.replaceState(null, 'new state name', '/route-minus-one-time-params');
    }
```

The idea is to replace the browser history with the current page's route minus whatever parameters you do not want stored in the browser history. This must be done in the attached callback (if you try doing this in the activated callback, it will not work since the router hasn't called window.history.pushState() yet).

Answer (score 0):

I already met this requirments but never used `refresh=true` for it. On route change and back button navigation normally your view models are called again so you can check for data and load it.

Here are two links that should help you:

[Aurelia Documentation regarding routing and additional data](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/4)

[Sharing data with a service](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/shared-state-in-aurelia/)

Comment: Not sure you understood the question (because I don't understand your answer). The issue is not how to store data past the lifetime of a view-model (that is the question it sounds like you are answering).